# Magento export order information

Tags: magento-1.8, orders, database, export

I need to export email adresses and phone numbers, in all my 65000 orders. Is this possible?

Comment: Can´t you just export all customers?

Comment: I did but it didnt contain any of the needed information

Comment: @Klettseb, yes its possible to do so create new custom export script and export order data through custom script.

Comment: Under System -> import/Export -> Profiles, I can create a customer export with phone numbers as well

Comment: Thanks but, I need to do it from the orders, not everyone with a order is a customer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the answer guys! Thanks to my tech who did this!

```
<?php
require_once('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app('default');        
$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/mysql4_order_collection');
$allIds = $orders->getAllIds();   
$mycsv = 'Name,Email,Telephone'."\n";
foreach($allIds as $thisId) {
    $myOrder = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($thisId);
    $mycsv .= '"'.$myOrder->getShippingAddress()->getName().'","'.$myOrder->getShippingAddress()->getEmail().'","'.$myOrder->getShippingAddress()->getTelephone().'"'."\n";
}
header('Content-Disposition:attachment;filename=customers.csv');
header('Content-Type:application/force-download');
echo $mycsv;    
exit; 
?>
```

Comment: Please flag this as the correct answer. I just tried it :)